# Дата/Время PHP

Tags: дата, php, mysql, время

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать данное: Я создаю новость в таблицу у меня помимо другой информации добавляется и время, как мне сделать такое что бы время и дата были в таком формате:

после добавления такое Добавлена 10 секунд назад и так далее...
На следующий день в таком формате: Добавлена: Вчера в 20:21 и т.д, ну и прошло 2 дня с момента добавления писать... как бы постоянно обновлялась. 
Добавлена 6 Февраля 20:21

Спасибо огромное кто поможет :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

зачем это в базе обновлять??? Храните в базе timestamp и выводите как вам захочется... Вы просто представьте если у вас будет 1млн новостей :) Вам не слабые сервера надо будет покупать, чтобы каждую секунду ВСЕ записи обновлять.

ps; гдето тут я уже видел похожий вопрос. почитайте про [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.datetime.php)
pps; если кратко, то суть: `$seconds_from_other_date = time() - $your_timestamp_in_db;` в переменной вы получите количество секунд, прошедших с момента публикации.
ppps; [мини пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735252/php-countdown-to-date)

Answer (score 1):

ИМХО бредовая идея обновлять постоянно это в базе, делайте как написал [@thunder](/users/9040/thunder), храните в базе timestamp, а затем при формировании страницы преобразуйте в скрипте так, как вам надо. Смотрите в сторону [функции date()](http://php.net/date)